# How command `make` link to Python lib?

Tags: makefile

A C++ project file, `xxx.cpp`, invoked python function as following:

```
  if(FindLoggingBehavior){

    // Initialize python module
    Py_Initialize();
    if(!Py_IsInitialized()){
        return 0;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/Users/abc/source/script/segment/')");
    pName = PyString_FromString("segment");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if(!pModule){
        printf("can't find segment.py");
        return 0;
    }
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    if(!pDict){
        printf("can't find dict");
        return 0;
    }
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "segment");
    if(!pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc)){
        printf("can't find function [segment]");
        return 0;
    }
```

When I run `make` to compile the project, the following errors have occurred:

```
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable ../../../../bin/clang-smartlog
CMakeFiles/clang-smartlog.dir/src/SmartLog.cpp.o: In function `main':
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x250): undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x255): undefined reference to 
`Py_IsInitialized'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x121c): undefined reference to 
`PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
 SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x122a): undefined reference to 
`PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x1236): undefined reference to 
`PyString_FromString'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x1248): undefined reference to 
`PyImport_Import'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x1263): undefined reference to 
`PyModule_GetDict'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x1285): undefined reference to 
`PyDict_GetItemString'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x12a0): undefined reference to 
`PyCallable_Check'
SmartLog.cpp:(.text.startup.main+0x35f5): undefined reference to 
`Py_Finalize'
CMakeFiles/clang-smartlog.dir/src/FindLoggingBehavior.cpp.o: In function 
`FindLoggingVisitor::spiltWord(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
FindLoggingBehavior.cpp: 

 (.text._ZN18FindLoggingVisitor9spiltWordENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_tra 
itsIcESaIcEEE+0x8c): undefined reference to `PyObject_CallFunction'
FindLoggingBehavior.cpp: 
  (.text._ZN18FindLoggingVisitor9spiltWordENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_tra 
itsIcESaIcEEE+0xdc): undefined reference to `PyList_GetItem'
FindLoggingBehavior.cpp: 
 (.text._ZN18FindLoggingVisitor9spiltWordENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_tra 
itsIcESaIcEEE+0x101): undefined reference to `PyString_AsString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/clang/tools/SmartLog/CMakeFiles/clang-smartlog.dir/build.make:445: recipe 
for target 'bin/clang-smartlog' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/clang-smartlog] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:26568: recipe for target 
'tools/clang/tools/SmartLog/CMakeFiles/clang-smartlog.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/clang/tools/SmartLog/CMakeFiles/clang-smartlog.dir/all] 
Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can `make` link to Python lib?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Can I use --ignore-error option?

Comment: That won't magically make the unresolved references resolve.

Comment: `make` doesn't particularly care or know what language it's processing or which libraries to link. You have to pass in the right options for the linker. Do you have the required Python headers installed somewhere?

Comment: What does your `Makefile` look like anyway? Does it attempt to infer a location for header files (perhaps by way of `./configure` or some similar automation) or does it just require you to pass in the correct values manually?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I add `LINK_LIBRARIES(".../libpython2.7.so")` to CMakeLists.